# Dragging Bootstrap 3 column background to the side of the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to stretch the `.black` column's black background to the left side of the browser. I am not sure how to accomplish that WITHOUT setting the container to a fluid container.

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/JEjZCYdPyl)

Is there a way to do this? I am avoiding the fluid container, because the content has to be in a fixed-width one.

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to happen?  Stretch the .black column to the left?

Comment: Can be, I need its content to be positioned as if it was a regular column inside a fixed-width container, but its background should extend to the left (only to the left) and touch the left side of a browser, just like if it was in a fluid container.

Comment: Why not just prevent the fixed width container from centering using a special class with 0 left margin? http://bootply.com/JHgk8lBxex

Comment: I don't want to prevent it from centering, the content of that black column has to behave like it was in a fixed-width container. I want only the background of that column to be stretched to the left. The content has to stay the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding an absolutely positioned div container with black background just after the container markup and making the container relative.

HTML

```
<div class="container relative">
<div class="col-md-3 black fill"></div>
```

CSS

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.fill {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-25%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here's a working [example](http://www.bootply.com/efvchoWoVd).

Explaination

1. Absolutely positioned elements basically float in the html document and position themselves as per the browser window depending on the top, left, right, bottom values.
2. However if the ancestor of an absolutely positioned element is relatively positioned, then the absolutely positioned elements place themselves **relative** to the parent container and thus the `relative` css class for the bootstrap container.
3. Since the width of absolutely positioned div is 25% as per the `col-md-3` class and to compensate for the left margin of the bootstrap container, we use a **negative** left value of 25% for our absolutely positioned div.
4. A height of 100% is required to snap the black background container to the bootstrap container height.

The above CSS styling properties when combined properly can give the desired result.

Comment: Well, the problem is that this container does not hold only those two columns, there is more content and I think it would mess some stuff a little bit. There is stuff above those columns and below them.

Comment: And the background color has to extended for this section only?

Comment: Yes, though using your help I kinda managed to apply this solution to the row, instead of the container. I will select your answer as correct, because it's awesome. If I run into any problems I will comment here, maybe you will have some spare time then to address an issue :). Thank you, friend.